# GWT CellTree @UIHandler SelectionChanged

Tags: java, gwt

I am using the GWT CellTree class and I want to be able to update another UI element on the page when the selection changes.

I have this:

```
@UiField (provided = true)
CellTree folderTree;
```

Which I populate with data on the page load, then I need the @UIiHandler, something like:

```
@UiHandler("folderTree")
void onTreeCellChange(????? e){
    //update UI    
}
```

I've already tried things like:

```
ValueChangeEvent<List<Folder>> //List<Folder> being the underlying class for the CellTree.
SelectionHandler<CellTree>
ClickEvent
```

In all the above cases, I get a *Deferred binding failed* on form load.
I feel like I am missing something simple, but cannot seem to find it with my google-fu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add handler to NodeInfo of TreeViewModel of CellTree.

Here is example how it is possible to do:

First of all let's define what is folder:

```
// the simplest possible folder even without subfolders just to make example working
public class Folder {
    private String name;

    public Folder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Let's say part of your ui.xml is the following:

```
<g:HorizontalPanel>
    <cellview:CellTree ui:field="folderTree"/>
    <g:Label ui:field="folderName"/>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Than you have UiBinder:

```
public static interface Binder extends UiBinder<HorizontalPanel, BinderOwner> {}
```

Here is how you define FolerTreeModel that is required for your CellTree:

```
public static class FolderTreeModel implements TreeViewModel {
    private final ListDataProvider<Folder> dataProvider;
    private final CellPreviewEvent.Handler<Folder> folderSelectionHandler;

    public FolderTreeModel(List<Folder> folders, CellPreviewEvent.Handler<Folder> folderSelectionHandler) {
        this.folderSelectionHandler = folderSelectionHandler;
        dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Folder>(folders);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TreeViewModel.NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<Folder>(dataProvider, new AbstractCell<Folder>() {
            // simple renderer that renders folder name
            @Override 
            public void render(Context context, Folder value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                sb.appendEscaped(value.getName());
            }
        }, 
        new SingleSelectionModel<Folder>(), // using single selection model
        folderSelectionHandler, // add handler to the node info
        null); // value updater can be null
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
        return false; // I will say that every node is not leaf for simplicity 
    }
 }
```

And your BinderOwner class:

```
public static class BinderOwner {
    @UiField(provided = true)
    CellTree folderTree;
    @UiField
    Label folderName; //your other UI element that you will change: show the name of selected folder

    public BinderOwner() {
         //List of folders to show something
         ArrayList<Folder> folders = new ArrayList<Folder>();
         folders.add(new Folder("A"));
         folders.add(new Folder("B"));
         folders.add(new Folder("C"));

         // define folder tree
         folderTree = new CellTree(new FolderTreeModel(folders, new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<Folder>() {
             // this is your handler
             @Override 
             public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Folder> event) {
                 // set folder name to label on folder selection
                 folderName.setText(event.getValue().getName());
             }
         }), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, adding that I can then use something like this on the form?
    @UiHandler("folderTree")
    void onTreeCellChange(SelectionChangeEvent e){}

Comment: You will not need @UiHandler after that because you will implement it inside onSelectionChange() method.

Comment: You have more than one way to add handlers if you use UiBinder. One of them is using @UiHandler annotation for the handler method. This approach is good if GWT creates component for you from UiBinder xml template. Another way is create component manually like you did with @UiField(provided = true). In this case you may add handler during component creation directly in the Java code like in my example.

Comment: I clarified the question a little, but my goal is to update another UI element on the page, is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. I changed my answer to show you concrete example how to do that.